# Left Join with last insert record from left table and all record form right table

Tags: mysql, database, join

fetch data with **join** with **last insert record** from left table based on company id and all record from right table doesn't matter it has any match record in left table.

```
**company_list**
id
company_id
company_name
company_address1
company_address2
company_phone
company_headoffice
active

**company_subscription_list** table field name is 
id
company_id
company_name
company_address1
company_address2
company_phone
company_headoffice
active
```

and i am using this query for fecth record

```
SELECT *, c.id AS main_id
FROM company_list as c
LEFT JOIN company_subscription_list as s ON c.company_id = s.company_id
where s.id IN (select max(id) from company_subscription_list GROUP BY company_id)
```

but its not showing result of those company who didn't subscribe yet.

Need Help.

Comment: Changing `where` to `and` might help but, if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: 4th line looks screwed up

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1150/1/0    @strawberry

i want all record form my company_list table

Answer (score 1):

You have to put you condition in your join condition. Doing so, you will not lose lines :

```
SELECT *, c.id AS main_id 
FROM company_list as c 
LEFT JOIN company_subscription_list as s 
    ON c.company_id = s.company_id 
    AND s.id IN (select max(id) from company_subscription_list GROUP BY company_id)
```

Try on this link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5db87/4

Comment: Thanks a lot @coytech